# Running JQuery in Safari

Tags: jquery, safari

running and debugging in Safari is totally new to me.

I have a login page that works on all browsers apart from Safari.

I have managed to find the Web Inspector for this browser and it gives me this error:

Can't find variable: $

Now, I am not sure where to go from here.

Is this a case of compatibility between Safari and Jquery I needs to know about?

These are my Includes in my master page (I am using asp.net)

```
<script type="application/javascript" src="http://myurl/Scripts/json2.js"></script>
<script type="application/javascript" src="http://myurl/Scripts/jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>
<script type="application/javascript" src="http://myurl/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="application/javascript" src="../Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../Styles/jquery-ui.css" />
<script type="application/javascript" src="../Scripts/jquery.animate-shadow-min.js"></script>
<script type="application/javascript" src="../Scripts/jquery.animate-shadow.js"></script>
```

This is my calling code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        function LogIn() {
            var _username = document.getElementById('<%=txtUsername.ClientID%>');
            var _password = document.getElementById('<%=txtPassword.ClientID%>');


            if (_username.value != '' && _password.value != '') {

                jQuery(function ($) {
                    $("#lblLoginError").html('Logging you in...');
                    btnLogIn.enabled = false;
                    btnForgotPassword.enabled = false;
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "LogIn.aspx/Login",
                        data: JSON.stringify({
                            Username: _username.value,
                            Password: _password.value
                        }),
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function (msg) {
                            if (msg.d == 'OK') {
                                document.location.href = 'Manager.aspx';
                            }
                            else {
                                $("#lblLoginError").html(msg.d);
                                btnLogIn.enabled = true;
                            }
                        },
                        error: function (msg) {
                            $("#lblLoginError").html('Server Error');
                            btnLogIn.enabled = true;
                        }
                    });
                });
            }
            else {
                $("#lblLoginError").html('Both Username and Password must be supplied.');
            }
        }
</script>
```

Please advise me?

Thanks

Comment: No. It's not, it's either the execution of your scripts that leverage jQuery come BEFORE jQuery is included, or you have another library that conflicts with it. Use `jQuery(function($){` instead of `$(document).ready(function(){`, does that resolve it?

Comment: Hi. Firstly, I am relieved that Safari will work with JQuery. I will amend my question to show you my includes

Comment: Hi again, I do not have $(document).ready(function() anywhere in my markup. I am using Ajax/jquery like:  "$.ajax({ type: "POST"," etc

Comment: You would need to first ensure that you've only bound jQuery functions in a ready handler. Please wrap all jQuery calls in `jQuery(function($){` and then at the end of the file, call `});` to close it. Furthermore, why do you load jQuery ui twice

Comment: Hi,  thanks for pointing the double reference out.  I did what you said but still get the error. I will post the code into my question (thanks for your time in all this)

Comment: Are you saying that your code works in all other browser except Safari?

Comment: yes, Chrome, firefox and IE

Comment: Hi all.  I just downloaded the latest version of Safari and it all works. So, I guess I am an idiot. However, @Ohgodwhy thanks for educating me about the jQuery(function($){ prefix. I used to be a ajax/asp.net programmer who hated javascript. I am a recent convert you see. thansk 4 ur time again